# Google chrome print page issues

Tags: google-chrome

For last few days i have been strucked with a problem which frustated me a lot ,while printing through a chrome browser some words and lines are missing which are displaying in print preview i don't know the reason the missing letters are not constant for each time different words are missing in different locations can anyone help?

Comment: I use Chrome on Ubuntu. I get the upgrades regularly. It prints really big, and select boxes are big black boxes.

Comment: Check this link https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gMWVqQRVz9Q

Comment: for me its on windows few times for me also letters will be big